# Expected Number of Actions in Program

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Let's say I have a simple programming language that controls a robot's movement.

These are the rules of the language:

```
A program is represented by a string of letters and numbers.
F --> move forwards 1 meter
B --> move backward 1 meter
L --> turn left 90 degrees
R --> turn right 90 degrees

A command followed by a number makes a for-loop. This means that the command is repeated that number of times.
 
Examples: 
"F" moves the robot forwards once
"F3" moves the robot forwards 3 times
"F30" moves the robot forwards 30 times
"FL" moves the robot forwards once, and turn left once
"F3L3" moves the robot forwards 3 times, and turns it left 3 times.
"L40" turns the robot left 40 times   
"F0" moves the robot forwards 0 times, i.e. does nothing
"F0L3" turns the robot left 3 times.

Extra:
A program cannot start with a number.
"turning left" means the robot rotates 90 degrees counterclockwise. It does not move forwards after rotating
"moving forwards" strictly means moving 1 meter.
```

My Question:

Let's say I have an unknown program that is *n* characters long. "Characters" means letters and digits. For the first black space representing a character, I randomly put either "F", "L", "R", or "B". For each black space after that, I randomly put either "F", "L", "R", "B" or one of the digits 0-9. This way, I get a program of *n* characters.

1. What is the expected number of commands(moving forwards/backwards 1 meter or turning left/right 90 degrees) the robot performs?
2. If the robot starts at the origin facing in the positive y-direction, what is the expected coordinate position of the robot?

I think geometric distribution might help, but I don't really know how.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [[1]] What about F0F00F000 ? [[2]] This is 2D Brownian Motion ! [[3]] Most likely , the movements may tend to cancel each other , hence Starting Point is most likely. [[4]] Beyond that , it is likely to lie on a Circle. [[5]] You should include Context : Why you want to Solve this ? What was your attempt ? Where you got this Problem ?

Comment: @Prem thanks for the suggestions. I fixed the question for [1]. For [5], this is a problem I came up with on my own. I didn't really have any idea where to begin for the first question, I thought geometric distribution might help but I couldn't figure out how. For the second question, I don't know why I didn't think of that. But you're right, I should have added any attempts, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**

Not a full step-by-step solution, just an overview of how to solve the problem.

**Probability Vector**

Define the following probability vector:

$$
\mathbf{a}_{i}=
\begin{Bmatrix}
x_{1}^{[i]} \\ x_{2}^{[i]}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

- $x_{1}^{[i]}$ denotes the probability that the program has action as the $i$-th digit
- $x_{2}^{[i]}$ denotes the probability that the program has repetition as the $i$-th digit.

Because the first digit has to be an action, we have:

$$
\mathbf{a}_{1} =
\begin{Bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

**Recursive Relation**

We have the following recursive relation:

$$
\mathbf{a}_{i+1}=\mathbf{M}\mathbf{a}_{i}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1 \\ 
1- \alpha & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
x_{1}^{[i]} \\ x_{2}^{[i]}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

$\alpha$ is the probability that an action is followed by another action. Therefore the first column of $\mathbf{M}$ represents possible branching of the program, including the probability of each branch. The second column is the same, however, repetition must be followed by action (if I get your problem correctly), hence $1$ and $0$.

**Expected Value**

Define expected value vector as the following:

$$
\mathbf{E}^{[n]}=
\begin{Bmatrix}
E_{1}^{[n]} \\
E_{2}^{[n]}
\end{Bmatrix}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}
\mathbf{M}^{i}\mathbf{a}_{1}
$$

- $E_{1}^{[n]}$ is the expected number of actions in a program of length $n$
- $E_{2}^{[n]}$ is the expected number of repetition numbers in a program of length $n$

You can compute the matrix geometric sum using eigenvalues & eigenvectors of $\mathbf{M}$. If you are not obliged to solve by hand, then it is very simple to compute the sum with programs like MATLAB.

**Second Question**

As mentioned in the comment, the available steps are symmetric, in the sense that each action has an action that cancels it. Consequently, for any program such as $F3L3$ there is a program such as $B3R3$ with equal probability, thus when averaged will result in the origin.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution was helpful, but I'm afraid you misunderstood the question a little in terms of the language. A digit is not necessarily followed by a letter. For example, ```F30``` means to move forwards 30 times.

Comment: @MeltedStatementRecognizing ah I see, then you just need to adjust the second column of $\mathbf{M}$ accordingly

Comment: I apologize, but I don't quite understand. By using your method, wouldn't it be more like  considering the ```3``` and ```0``` separately instead of treating it as a single number ```30```?